# ¿Cómo podría mantener un script de javascript ejecutado todo el tiempo que el usuario esté en la web?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, formularios

Holaa, voy a procurar explicarme bien porque es algo difícil de explicar.
A ver, estoy haciendo un sistema de seguridad que determina a través de una función de php si un usuario tiene comportamientos maliciosos, a través de esa función de php utilizo JavaScript para que a través de un condicional guarde el dato (los puntos de 0-100) en localstorage para posteriormente utilizarlo en el index.php. 
Para situarnos mejor, es como un sistema de puntos que si alcanzas el máximo simplemente los divs de la página principal se ocultan.
Total, lo que llevo hecho por el momento funciona, pero me gustaría que el usuario si llega al máximo de puntos le aparezca directamente el error, no que tenga que actualizar la página para que se le muestre. Ya que además tengo checks que "suman puntos" a la hora de hacer determinadas opciones.

ERROR:

> assets/php/setting.php:1
> GET http://127.0.0.1/tusc/trie/assets/php/setting.php net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

**UPDATE DE CODE**

Load Page JavaScript Code:

```
const value = localStorage.getItem('ip_f');
var badip = <?php echo $badip;?>;
if(value >0){   // Function which will determinate if the user has visited the webpage before or not


    var car = 1;  //Addition of 1 point in case it has visited before
    var ip_f = parseInt(value) + parseInt(car);
    localStorage.setItem('ip_f', ip_f);
        console.log('this user has visited teh web before'+ip_f);
}
else{
if (badip >= 40) {
    var ip_w ="0";          //Addition in case the ip is malicious or detected bad behaviour.
    var badip = "40";

    var ip_f = parseInt(ip_w) + parseInt(badip);


localStorage.setItem('ip_f', ip_f);

// Ontener el valor de una clave


}
else{
console.log('the script hasn"t" charged or the ip isnt fraudulent');
}

}
```

setting.php FILE:

```
  <?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
ob_end_clean();
echo "foo";
flush();
while( true ) {
$value = '<script type="text/javascript">


var value = localStorage.getItem("ip_f");


        if (value >= 50) {
           $("#root").hide();
           $("#detected").show();
           console.log("dumb_checked"); // console check data;
       }


       else {
           console.log("charge");
     }


</script>';
echo $value;
flush();
sleep(1);
}
```

Index.php JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var source;
    //Primero comprobar que exista compatibilidad del navegador
    if (typeof (EventSource) === "undefined") {
        alert('Tu navegador no tiene soporte para el objeto EventSource');
        return;
    }
    //Apunta al script PHP que le devuelve la hora por streaming
    source = new EventSource("./assets/php/setting.php");
    source.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log('streaming SSE abierto');
    };
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log('recibido mensaje de streaming');
        document.getElementById("html").innerHTML = event.data;
       
    }
    /*
    "source.onmessage" es igual que escribir el siguiente event listener:
    source.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    }, false);
    */
    source.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log('ERROR en EventSource keep data on log file');
        //Los códigos de estado de "readyState" son los mismos que un recurso XMLHttpRequest
        /*if(event.target.readyState == 0){
        //Se cerró la conexión
        }*/
    }


    $("#html").bind({
        copy: function () {
            var ip_w = localStorage.getItem('ip_f');
            var ctrl = "5";
            var ip_f = parseInt(ip_w) + parseInt(ctrl);
            localStorage.setItem('ip_f', ip_f);
            console.log(ip_w);
        },
        paste: function () {
            console.log('c+v det'); //working on it later
        },
        cut: function () {
            console.log('c+x det'); //working on it later      
            var ip_w = localStorage.getItem('ip_f');
            var ctrl = "5";
            var ip_f = parseInt(ip_w) + parseInt(ctrl);
            localStorage.setItem('ip_f', ip_f);
            console.log(ip_f+'Function logged successfully c + w');
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Creo que lo que podrías hacer es usar un `setTiemout` que periódicamente revise/modifique los puntos en tu `localStorage` y que detecte cuando ya no hay más puntos y ejecute la función que oculta o destruye los divs.

Comment: @FranAcuna supongo te refieres a `setInterval`.

Comment: Una de las posibles formas de hacerlo es usando [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @MauricioContreras!

Comment: @FranAcuna podrías adjuntarme algún ejemplo de su uso? Para guiarme

Comment: @Emeeus Veo que es PHP, ¿funcionará si todo el sistema de seguridad que hace la adición de puntos va por JS y JQuery?

Comment: Ningún sistema de seguridad delegado al lado cliente (Javascript) es confiable.

Comment: Claro, la mecánica funcionaría, pero el usuario puede cambiar lo que quiera en el cliente, mostrar los divs que no quieres mostrarle por ejemplo, también podría enviar cualquier información que quiera al backend, engañando un "buen comportamiento".

Comment: Entiendo, la detección en sí es únicamente para tener el control de unas determinadas acciones que posteriormente se enviarán a un panel, ese sería más o menos esa funcionalidad del sistema de seguridad, el sistema de detección interna del formulario va a través de php y sin contar con ese "sistema de seguridad"

Comment: @Emeeus He estado probando el code, pero me arroja el siguiente error en la consola:
assets/php/setting.php:1 
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1/tusc/trie/assets/php/setting.php net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
No sé si es debido a que estoy usando localhost o por una mal función del code. Voy a actualizar el code con el nuevo código y el error